# Navigating through pages using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
def get_link(search_term,page):
try:
    Pinbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/input')
    Pinbox.send_keys(Pincode)
    Pinbox.submit()
except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    return
try:    
    grocery="https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={}&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=GROCERY&as-show=on&as=off"
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')
    stem = grocery.format(search_term)
    url_template = stem + '&as-pos=1&as-type=HISTORY&as-backfill=on&page='
    next=url_template+str(page)
    print(next)
    if page > 1:
        return next
    else:
        return Pinbox and stem
except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    return        

def PID():
    for page in range(1,20):
        path=get_link(term,page)
        driver.get(path)
        id=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-id]')
        for i in id:
            results=i.get_attribute('data-id')
            print(results)
            FSN_List.append(results)

PID()
```

unable to navigate through pages,get an error selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string

Comment: Returning nothing instead of a string etc path=get_link(term,page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created a different function,

```
def pin(Pincode):
    try:
        Pinbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/input')
        Pinbox.send_keys(Pincode)
        Pinbox.submit()
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        return
```

this resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Exception appears, because you return None, from get_link function. In get_link function first step is finding element, but you have not moved to the site yet:

```
try:
    Pinbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/form/input')
    Pinbox.send_keys(Pincode)
    Pinbox.submit()
except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    return
```

you should first provide link to .get() driver funciton, thand then looking for elements

Comment: i have given the link before

Comment: this code is working for page 1 its not going to the next page respectively

Comment: @ Maryna Grushevskaya i have resolved the issue